# How to reverse the stacking order in stacked area graph using ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

[image]I want to plot stacked area graph using ggplot2, but I found my result is different from that in the book (R Graphics Cookbook Figure 4-22)

`library(gcookbook)`

`library(plyr)`

`ggplot(uspopage, aes(x=Year, y=Thousands, fill=AgeGroup, order=desc(AgeGroup))) + geom_area(colour="black", size=.2, alpha=.4) + scale_fill_brewer(palette="Blues")`

The stacking order could not be reversed (In the book, the ">64" should be in the bottom). Is there something wrong in this process?

Comment: I do not know your `ggplot2` version, but with 2.1.0 version: "The order aesthetic is officially deprecated. It never really worked, and 
was poorly documented." https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/releases

Comment: Reorder the actual data frame, `uspopage`. If you want the legend to be reordered, you could reverse the level order.

Comment: Which is to say, `uspopage$AgeGroup = factor(uspopage$AgeGroup, levels = rev(levels(uspopage$AgeGroup)))`

Comment: Factors is the way to do this: http://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/7433_4537ea5073dc4162950abb715f513469.html

Comment: @Chris: Reordering the factor levels only affects the legend; if you want to change the stacking order, you got to rearrange/reorder the whole data frame before handing it over to `ggplot`. This is not really intuitive.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An adhoc approach is to reorder you data. Instead of

```
AgeGroup 
      <5     
    5-14    
   15-24
```

you want

```
AgeGroup 
>64     
55-64  
45-54
```

So you could take the last element and put it in first place, the second last element in second place, ... Something similar to `c("A", "B", "C", "D")[4:1]` happens when you use

```
swap <- uspopage[nrow(uspopage):1,] 
ggplot(swap, aes(x=Year, y=Thousands, fill=AgeGroup, order=desc(AgeGroup))) + 
geom_area(colour="black", size=.2, alpha=.4) + scale_fill_brewer(palette="Blues")
```

---

2016-06-02: I gave some explanation after request in comment.

Comment: It worked well. But could you give some explanation for it?